# Which is more correct: 'backend' or 'dashboard'

Tags: content-management-system

In programming terms, the 'back end' is the part of the software that the user does not interact with, or at least, shouldn't. 'front end' would be the part where the user has (e.g.) a GUI to use the software.

In Web Development, however, I've seen the term 'back end' being used for the administration environment and 'front end' for the live website that theoretically everyone could access and view.

The term 'dashboard' is also used to name an admin environment within a website, however, I've seen this being used less.

Now, I'm wondering, would 'backend' or 'dashboard' be more suitable for an admin environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backend on a development level refers to server-side development and the handling of server-side information. Backend is used in reference to the administration dashboard when it relates to the management of that data. For example, a dashboard that allows an admin user to manage the database is called backend because it handles the management of the server-side data. Technically, however, that dashboard is still a front-end aspect of development. I would lean towards using dashboard when referencing the admin environment because technically it is not backend development. I hope this helped.